# CORS error while accessing azure databricks rest api from front end

Tags: angular, azure, api, azure-databricks

CORS error while accessing azure databricks rest api from front end

/api/2.0/jobs/run/list while accessing this from postman I am getting the response as expected

But while accessing the same api from front end it’s throwing cORS
‘ local host:4200 has been blocked by Cors policy: Response to preflight: it doesn’t have http ok status

How can I solve this issue

Comment: Could you please share more details on the command which you are running along with the screenshot of the error message which you are experiencing?

Comment: Access to XMLhttpRequest at .net/api/2.0/runs/list from origin is blocked by Cors policy: Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access controls check: It doesn’t have http ok status.   I am using angular 10 to integrate this API to front end

Comment: Hi sai, did you get any answer. I am also facing same issue

Comment: Did you add your server host url to trusted origin list in your api ? Which framework do you use ? Will be better if you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using your backend to mediate between the frontend and DataBricks api, or if you are in azure environment you can try making a functions api that brings trigger from the frontend and hits the databricks api.